# On Oreo, is it possible to mute individual notifications belonging to the same notification channel?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I have a bunch of notifications for new messages (MessagingStyle, one notification contains one or more messages with the same user), and I want to play sound when a new message arrives *now*. Sometimes I want to update the notification silently, though. For instance:

- On system boot up, I want to present old messages to the user without sound
- When the application is not connected, I want to update the notifications to remove the “Reply” button, and vice versa
- When an application receives a message that was posted some time in the past, I don't want to alert the user as they may have read the message elsewhere.

It works fine on L but Oreo seems to be playing sound for every notification fire or update. Is there a way to work around this behavior?

Comment: guess you would have to delay them and then send them into the according channel, which has no notification sound configured... don't think one has access to notifications, which were already sent into a channel (which means, they were already delivered). it's rather a theoretical question, unless you'd add the code which works as expected on previous API levels.

Comment: i've tried creating another notification channel with low importance and it seems to work. it doesn't matter which channel the notification was posted on before; the channel used to update the notification produces the desired result. it seems a bit of a roundabout way to do things though; not sure how to call this new notification channel.. “new message (async)”?